# Change buttons to make the Traffic light Auto

Tags: javascript

I have this code and I want there just to be one button called Auto. The auto button should do what it already does but I tried to delete the other buttons and it didn't work. It just deleted the traffic lights.
Any help?
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#controlPanel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#traffic-light {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bulb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}

#controlPanel>h1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="controlPanel">
  <h1 id="stopButton" class="button">Stop</h1>
  <h1 id="slowButton" class="button">Slow</h1>
  <h1 id="goButton" class="button">Go</h1>
  <h1 id="Lights" class="button">Clear</h1>
  <h1 id="autoLights" class="button">Auto</h1>
</div>

<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('stopButton').onclick = stopRed;
document.getElementById('slowButton').onclick = slowYellow;
document.getElementById('goButton').onclick = goGreen;
document.getElementById('Lights').onclick = Lights;
document.getElementById('autoLights').onclick = autoLights;

function stopRed() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function slowYellow() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function goGreen() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}


function Lights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}


function lightOne(num) {
  Lights();
  switch (num) {
    case 1:
      stopRed();
      break;
    case 2:
      slowYellow();
      break;
    case 3:
      goGreen();
      break;
    default:
      alert("you made some error");
  }
}

counter = 0;
maxSec = 3;

function timer() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    counter++;
    lightOne(counter);
    if (counter == maxSec) {
      return;
    }
    timer();
  }, 2000);
}

function autoLights() {
  counter = 1;
  lightOne(counter);
  timer();
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that your error is that you are simply removing the buttons from your html, but you also must remove the `document.getElementById(...).onclick` because that will raise an error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#controlPanel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#traffic-light {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bulb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}

#controlPanel>h1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="controlPanel">
  <!--<h1 id="stopButton" class="button">Stop</h1>
  <h1 id="slowButton" class="button">Slow</h1>
  <h1 id="goButton" class="button">Go</h1>
  <h1 id="Lights" class="button">Clear</h1>-->
  <h1 id="autoLights" class="button">Auto</h1>
</div>

<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*document.getElementById('stopButton').onclick = stopRed;
document.getElementById('slowButton').onclick = slowYellow;
document.getElementById('goButton').onclick = goGreen;
document.getElementById('Lights').onclick = Lights;*/
document.getElementById('autoLights').onclick = autoLights;

function stopRed() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function slowYellow() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function goGreen() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}


function Lights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}


function lightOne(num) {
  Lights();
  switch (num) {
    case 1:
      stopRed();
      break;
    case 2:
      slowYellow();
      break;
    case 3:
      goGreen();
      break;
    default:
      alert("you made some error");
  }
}

counter = 0;
maxSec = 3;

function timer() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    counter++;
    lightOne(counter);
    if (counter == maxSec) {
      return;
    }
    timer();
  }, 2000);
}

function autoLights() {
  counter = 1;
  lightOne(counter);
  timer();
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.